# C creating processes with Fork()

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

```
  int main()
{
     int i;
     int status;

     for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         if(fork() == 0){
             sleep(1);
         }
     }

     printf("This is the end.\n");
     
     return 0;
}
```

I need to change the code so that exactly 4 child processes will be created. I have tried a few things but Im not sure how to do it.

Comment: Add `return 0` or `exit(0)` after `sleep`.

Comment: Remember: When you clone yourself with `fork()` your program continues as if it was not a clone. You **must** prevent your clones from creating additional clones.

Comment: @ggorlen I tried exit(0) inside the loop, I didn;'t think of break and I also thought I needed to do it using the status variable so I tried to return fork to status and do sth with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prevent the child processes from creating new child processes. To do so, just exit the loop in a child process.

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if(fork() == 0) {
        // Only the child process will execute this
        sleep(1);
        break;
    }
}
```